# Powershell : how to get window titles when MainWindowTitle is empty

Tags: powershell

I am not a windows expert (so I may use wrong term).

I have an application that opens new windows as "subprocess" but they have no MainWindowTitle whereas, of course, I can see a proper title in their window bar.

How can I list the subprocess with the corresponding title ?

```
 Get-Process  MoTTY | ft id, Name, MainWindowTitle

   Id Name  MainWindowTitle
   -- ----  ---------------
 1140 MoTTY
 3808 MoTTY
10880 MoTTY
```

Regards
JP

Comment: Are you working with MobaXterm?

Comment: Yes right. If there is a solution with cygwin/bash, it will be fine too.